# How to call a function when 3 characters are typed in jQuery autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want an array of "tags" to be updated when the user has typed 3 characters into the autocomplete form. Basically, I want to do this

```
<!-- when 3 characters are typed in autocomplete form, make this $.get call -->
var tags = [];
$.get("myaspscript", function(data, status) {
    tags = data.split(", ");
    $(result).html( data );
});
```

How can I do this? Thanks for the help.

```
<body>

<label for="autocomplete">Search: </label>
<input id="autocomplete">

<script>
var tags = [];
$.get("myaspscript", function(data, status) {
    tags = data.split(", ");
    $(result).html( data );
});

$( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
  minLength: 3,

  source: function( request, response ) {
          var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( request.term ), "i" );
          response( $.grep( tags, function( item ){
              return matcher.test( item );
          }) );
      }
});

</script>

</body>
```

Comment: Make a `counter` variable, increment it every time a user types a character, if it is equal to three, run the rest of the block and reset counter to zero.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if autocomplete has an option for that, but you could check it manually:

```
  $('#autocomplete')
    .bind('keypress keyup', function(e){
      if ($(this).val().length < 3 ) return;
      //make your $.get call
    });
  });
```